# Why isn't Clojure's clj-http sending the JSON form params properly?

Tags: clojure

It doesn't appear that the clj-http 0.4.0 library is sending JSON params properly; however, it was supposed to be patched in 0.3.4:

- https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http/pull/52
- https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http/blob/master/changelog.org

It's hard to tell exactly what's being sent because setting `debug` to `true` in the clj-http request options displays the request params as:

```
:body #<StringEntity org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity@714c7f58>
```

Why doesn't is display them in a viewable form?

So I used netcat to see what's being sent, and this is what it showed:

**This works...**

```
(client/request
 {:method :post
  :url "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/GremlinPlugin/graphdb/execute_script"
  :body (json/generate-string {:script "g.v(id)", :params {:id 321} })
  :content-type :json})
```

Netcat output...

```
POST /db/data/ext/GremlinPlugin/graphdb/execute_script HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 50
Host: localhost:7474
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.3 (java 1.5)

"{\"params\":{\"id\":321},\"script\":\"g.v(id)\"}"
```

**This doesn't work...**

```
(client/request
 {:method :post
  :url "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/GremlinPlugin/graphdb/execute_script",
  :form-params {:script "g.v(id)", :params {:id 321}}
  :content-type :json})
```

Netcat output...

```
POST /db/data/ext/GremlinPlugin/graphdb/execute_script HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 37
Host: localhost:7474
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.3 (java 1.5)

{"params[id]":321,"script":"g.v(id)"}
```

This is my first bout with Clojure and clj-http so I'm probably missing something -- what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug introduced in a recent pull request for nested form params. I've fixed it here: https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http/commit/2e5aab82029b46f0b1e28d53734c642582306539